# Accent folding for a custom javascript autocomplete

Tags: javascript, jquery, autocomplete

I've decided to build my own javascript autocomplete search because I have a list of over 120,000 elements in an array and quite simply jQuery UI Autocomplete and jQuery Autocomplete just didn't work out for me.

It's actually proving to be quite easy and so far with a list of 80,000 elements it's really quick. Anyhow, I desperately need to introduce accent folding into my autocomplete but I have no clue how I should go about it so that it remains efficient.

Here is my JS:

```js
   var arr = ["Wayne Réviér", "Wayne Röllo", "Wayne Rolls", "Wayne Grety",    "Wayne Rüm", "Wayne Erry"]; //Example list.

    var searchBox = document.getElementById('searchBox');
    jQuery('#searchBox').on('input propertychange paste', function() {
    $('div').html("");
      var listCounter = 0;
     setTimeout(function(){ 
         if(searchBox.value.length >= 3) { //restrict to 3+ characters.
       for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) { //loop through array
        if( listCounter <= 4) { //only show top 5 results.
         searchBoxLower = searchBox.value.toLowerCase(); //make comparing easier
         arrLower = arr[i].toLowerCase();
         if(arrLower.indexOf(searchBoxLower) > -1) {
           listCounter++; //result found. +1 counter.
                            $('div').append(arr[i]+"<br>");
          }
         } 
        }
       }
    
     }, 5);
    });
```

```html
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="searchBox"/>
<div>
</div>
```

How could I introduce accent folding into this? Also, if you catch anything that would increase efficiency I'd love to hear it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would probably make a RegExp test on the searchBoxLower. I'm not at home right now to test the code but I think this article might interest you.

http://alistapart.com/article/accent-folding-for-auto-complete

Most of the time when I need autocomplete search I am working with Ajax and a database and I replace all accent characters with their original form if I may say this like that. Ex. all the éèêàâôö, etc.. with 'e','a','o'. This makes the searching process a lot easier but it will give you more results.

I hope the article will help you.